# Kotlin and javax.validation.constraints.NotNull

Tags: kotlin, bean-validation, javax

Kotlin compiler inserts `@Nullable` and `@NotNull` from `org.jetbrains.annotations`, is it possible to insert also `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull` ?

Comment: Ofcourse you can. You just need to write a Kotlin compiler plugin. You can take a look at a sample here: https://github.com/Takhion/sample-kotlin-compiler-plugin

Comment: @Strelok Thanks. Maybe there is already a plugin?

Comment: @Strelok Kotlin compiler plugins are undocumented, unsupported, not intended to be used by anyone outside JetBrains and guaranteed to break in the future, so please don't answer any Kotlin questions with "just need to write a compiler plugin".

Comment: @Romper did you find a solution to this? I'm after the same thing :)

Comment: One year later, any progress?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sure it is even if it’s not obvious.

```
@field:NotNull val valName: String?
```

But I prefer to use:

```
@field:NotEmpty val valName: String
```

Since I don’t think it’s a good idea to destroy the magic of null safe provided by Kotlin and have to manage later optional values.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such compiler plugin available at the moment.
This is the list of available compiler plugins:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add dependency of [hibernate validator](https://hibernate.org/validator/) just like below

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation("org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator")
    ...
}
```

After that, you can `import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull`